# Autofac: Overriding registration target type from a module

Tags: autofac

I want to create an Autofac `Module` that overrides registration target type based on certain criteria. However the new type would have the same constructor and should be created using same parameter overrides as the original type.

I can use `AttachToComponentRegistration` to decide whether the registration should be overridden, but the overriding itself poses a problem. I suppose I need to replace the `IInstanceActivator` (specifically `ReflectionActivator`), but I do not see a way to get full information about existing `ReflectionActivator` — there seems to be no property to get configured parameters, for example.

Example (simplified code):

```cs
protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration) {
    base.AttachToComponentRegistration(componentRegistry, registration);
    var reflectionActivator = ((ComponentRegistration)registration).Activator as ReflectionActivator;
    if (reflectionActivator == null)
        return;

    var replacementType = ReplaceType(reflectionActivator.LimitType);
    if (replacementType == reflectionActivator.LimitType)
        return;

    ((ComponentRegistration)registration).Activator = new ReflectionActivator(
         replacementType,
         reflectionActivator.ConstructorFinder,
         reflectionActivator.ConstructorSelector,
         configuredParameters: ???, // how to get this?
         configuredProperties: ???  // or this?
    );
}
```

Is this something that can be done easier and am I just missing something here?

Comment: Why don't you just override the registration in your modele? So `builder.Register<MyNewType>.As<IMyInterface>` because if you don't provide the `.PreserveExistingDefaults()` modifier Autofac will just override the previous registration.

Comment: @nemesv I am probably a bit unclear — what I want to do is replace certain target types with with a different (dynamically generated) type that has same constructor. In your approach I have to either know all the types statically in advance (I do not) or have a way to find out registration parameters to rebuild registration (which returns to my original question).

Comment: @AndreyShchekin It's difficult to get what you want to do, could you post example code please.

Comment: @AlexandrNikitin I have added a code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReflectionActivator contains configuredParameters and configuredProperties in its private fields. You can read them via Reflection

```
var configuredParameters = (IEnumerable<Parameter>)typeof(ReflectionActivator).GetField("_configuredParameters", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(reflectionActivator);

var configuredProperties = (IEnumerable<Parameter>)typeof(ReflectionActivator).GetField("_configuredProperties", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(reflectionActivator);
```

And a working example:

```
class Program
{
    interface IInterface
    {
    }

    class MyClass : IInterface
    {
        private readonly string _name;

        public MyClass(string name)
        {
            _name = name;
        }

        protected MyClass()
        {
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", GetType(), _name);
        }
    }

    class MyReplacementClass : MyClass
    {
        private readonly string _name;

        public MyReplacementClass(string name)
        {
            _name = name;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", GetType(), _name);
        }
    }

    class MyModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterType<MyClass>().As<IInterface>().WithParameter("name", "Parameter");
        }

        protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry,
            IComponentRegistration registration)
        {
            var reflectionActivator = ((ComponentRegistration) registration).Activator as ReflectionActivator;
            if (reflectionActivator == null)
                return;

            var replacementType = ReplaceType(reflectionActivator.LimitType);
            if (replacementType == reflectionActivator.LimitType)
                return;

            var configuredParameters = (IEnumerable<Parameter>)typeof(ReflectionActivator).GetField("_configuredParameters",
                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(reflectionActivator);

            var configuredProperties = (IEnumerable<Parameter>)typeof(ReflectionActivator).GetField("_configuredProperties",
                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(reflectionActivator);

            ((ComponentRegistration) registration).Activator = new ReflectionActivator(
                replacementType,
                reflectionActivator.ConstructorFinder,
                reflectionActivator.ConstructorSelector,
                configuredParameters,
                configuredProperties
                );
        }

        private Type ReplaceType(Type limitType)
        {
            return typeof (MyReplacementClass);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builer = new ContainerBuilder();
        builer.RegisterModule<MyModule>();

        using (var container = builer.Build())
        {
            var myClass = container.Resolve<IInterface>();
            Console.WriteLine(myClass);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's unfortunate, I'll have to submit an issue to Autofac if I go on with side-project that requires this. But it is a valid answer.